# Heroku : Application Error 503 when running RoR app

Tags: heroku, web-applications

I am trying to run my app on Heroku. I have done a rake db:migrate and confirmed all dependencies. I have also added devise secret key. Additionally, I have added Nodejs and Ruby to my build packs.

The build was successful! and yet when I open the application, it gives me a 503 error.

I have tried to analyse the log but am unable to find exactly what might be causing this issue. Here's the log, please help! -

```
>     -----> Ruby app detected
>     -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
>     -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.4.1
>     -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
>            Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
>            Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.2). We suggest you
> upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install
> bundler`.
>            Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
>            Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
>            Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
>            Using rake 12.3.1
>            Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
>            Using minitest 5.11.3
>            Using thread_safe 0.3.6
>            Using builder 3.2.3
>            Using erubi 1.7.1
>            Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
>            Using crass 1.0.4
>            Using rack 2.0.5
>            Using nio4r 2.3.1
>            Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
>            Using mini_mime 1.0.0
>            Using arel 9.0.0
>            Using mimemagic 0.3.2
>            Using execjs 2.7.0
>            Using aws-eventstream 1.0.0
>            Using aws-partitions 1.90.0
>            Using aws-sigv4 1.0.2
>            Using jmespath 1.4.0
>            Using bcrypt 3.1.12
>            Using msgpack 1.2.4
>            Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
>            Using ffi 1.9.23
>            Using bundler 1.15.2
>            Using climate_control 0.2.0
>            Using cocoon 1.2.11
>            Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
>            Using method_source 0.9.0
>            Using thor 0.20.0
>            Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
>            Using temple 0.8.0
>            Using tilt 2.0.8
>            Using multi_json 1.13.1
>            Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
>            Using pg 1.0.0
>            Using puma 3.11.4
>            Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
>            Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
>            Using tlsmail 0.0.1
>            Using turbolinks-source 5.1.0
>            Using tzinfo 1.2.5
>            Using i18n 1.0.1
>            Using nokogiri 1.8.2
>            Using rack-test 1.0.0
>            Using warden 1.2.7
>            Using sprockets 3.7.1
>            Using mail 2.7.0
>            Using marcel 0.3.2
>            Using autoprefixer-rails 8.5.2
>            Using uglifier 4.1.11
>            Using websocket-driver 0.7.0
>            Using bootsnap 1.3.0
>            Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
>            Using terrapin 0.6.0
>            Using coffee-script 2.4.1
>            Using aws-sdk-core 3.21.2
>            Using mime-types 3.1
>            Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
>            Using turbolinks 5.1.1
>            Using activesupport 5.2.0
>            Using haml 5.0.4
>            Using loofah 2.2.2
>            Using aws-sdk-kms 1.5.0
>            Using sass-listen 4.0.0
>            Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
>            Using globalid 0.4.1
>            Using activemodel 5.2.0
>            Using jbuilder 2.7.0
>            Using aws-sdk-s3 1.13.0
>            Using activejob 5.2.0
>            Using activerecord 5.2.0
>            Using paperclip 6.0.0
>            Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
>            Using sass 3.5.6
>            Using actionview 5.2.0
>            Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
>            Using actionpack 5.2.0
>            Using actioncable 5.2.0
>            Using actionmailer 5.2.0
>            Using activestorage 5.2.0
>            Using railties 5.2.0
>            Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
>            Using simple_form 4.0.1
>            Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
>            Using responders 2.4.0
>            Using jquery-rails 4.3.3
>            Using rails 5.2.0
>            Using sass-rails 5.0.7
>            Using devise 4.4.3
>            Bundle complete! 29 Gemfile dependencies, 89 gems now installed.
>            Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
>            Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
>            Bundle completed (3.48s)
>            Cleaning up the bundler cache.
>            Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.2). We suggest you
> upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install
> bundler`.
>            The latest bundler is 1.16.2, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
>            To update, run `gem install bundler`
>     -----> Installing node-v8.10.0-linux-x64
>     -----> Detecting rake tasks
>     -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
>            Running: rake assets:precompile
>            /tmp/build_f381a7cc4444b081c9f6475d04f8ebb1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/smtp.rb:806:
> warning: already initialized constant Net::SMTPSession
>            /tmp/build_f381a7cc4444b081c9f6475d04f8ebb1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/smtp.rb:806:
> warning: previous definition of SMTPSession was here
>            /tmp/build_f381a7cc4444b081c9f6475d04f8ebb1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:687:
> warning: already initialized constant Net::POP
>            /tmp/build_f381a7cc4444b081c9f6475d04f8ebb1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:687:
> warning: previous definition of POP was here
>            /tmp/build_f381a7cc4444b081c9f6475d04f8ebb1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:688:
> warning: already initialized constant Net::POPSession
>            /tmp/build_f381a7cc4444b081c9f6475d04f8ebb1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:688:
> warning: previous definition of POPSession was here
>            /tmp/build_f381a7cc4444b081c9f6475d04f8ebb1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:689:
> warning: already initialized constant Net::POP3Session
>            /tmp/build_f381a7cc4444b081c9f6475d04f8ebb1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:689:
> warning: previous definition of POP3Session was here
>            /tmp/build_f381a7cc4444b081c9f6475d04f8ebb1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:702:
> warning: already initialized constant Net::APOPSession
>            /tmp/build_f381a7cc4444b081c9f6475d04f8ebb1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:702:
> warning: previous definition of APOPSession was here
>            Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
>            Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
>            Asset precompilation completed (1.67s)
>            Cleaning assets
>            Running: rake assets:clean
>            /tmp/build_f381a7cc4444b081c9f6475d04f8ebb1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/smtp.rb:806:
> warning: already initialized constant Net::SMTPSession
>            /tmp/build_f381a7cc4444b081c9f6475d04f8ebb1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/smtp.rb:806:
> warning: previous definition of SMTPSession was here
>            /tmp/build_f381a7cc4444b081c9f6475d04f8ebb1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:687:
> warning: already initialized constant Net::POP
>            /tmp/build_f381a7cc4444b081c9f6475d04f8ebb1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:687:
> warning: previous definition of POP was here
>            /tmp/build_f381a7cc4444b081c9f6475d04f8ebb1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:688:
> warning: already initialized constant Net::POPSession
>            /tmp/build_f381a7cc4444b081c9f6475d04f8ebb1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:688:
> warning: previous definition of POPSession was here
>            /tmp/build_f381a7cc4444b081c9f6475d04f8ebb1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:689:
> warning: already initialized constant Net::POP3Session
>            /tmp/build_f381a7cc4444b081c9f6475d04f8ebb1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:689:
> warning: previous definition of POP3Session was here
>            /tmp/build_f381a7cc4444b081c9f6475d04f8ebb1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:702:
> warning: already initialized constant Net::APOPSession
>            /tmp/build_f381a7cc4444b081c9f6475d04f8ebb1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:702:
> warning: previous definition of APOPSession was here
>     ###### WARNING:
>            We detected that some binary dependencies required to
>            use all the preview features of Active Storage are not
>            present on this system.
>            
>            For more information please see:
>              https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku
>            
>     ###### WARNING:
>            No Procfile detected, using the default web server.
>            We recommend explicitly declaring how to boot your server process via a Procfile.
>            https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
>     -----> Discovering process types
>            Procfile declares types     -> (none)
>            Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, web, worker
>     -----> Compressing...
>            Done: 51.9M
```

Comment: what does Heroku logs says?

Answer (score 0):

As per the description provided it would be better if you could share the heroku logs as well but meanwhile as described about 503 status code.

A 503 error means "Service Unavailable".

Heroku returns a 503 error when an HTTP request times out between the Heroku routing mesh and your application, 
including when the application failed to boot.

This timeout limit is set to 30 seconds, as documented by Heroku, and shows up in the logs as follows.

Please find the below link to get a better understanding of the above description:

http://artsy.github.io/blog/2012/11/15/how-to-monitor-503s-and-timeout-on-heroku/

Check if your page load and queries are well inside the 30 seconds.

For query monitoring use "bullet gem" so that they can be minimized.

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Run console from more option on the right top of the application. [Open console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/om1PN.png) You can see this kind of console there and input *rails console* there. [heroku run rails console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzNGO.png)

Then, you will see the complete log of the application and you will find the correct issue that leads the application to 503 status. [My issue was adapter typo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yv1SH.png)